# Communication via stdout/stdin between py2exe executable and C# program

Tags: c#, python, python-2.7, py2exe

So here's my problem:

1. Python scripts launched from C# via the Process class require the -i switch to be passed to python.exe or else they don't send any output when I redirect the StandardXxx streams
2. I want to bundle my Python program with py2exe (or another similar setup, if one meets my needs)
3. py2exe does not seem to let me pass the -i switch in any obvious way, but it's giving my the same issue as running python.exe - it doesn't output anything when launched by my C# program. So I need a way to force it into a similar mode so I can actually receive and send messages over stdin/stdout. I found some similar problems when it's built with "windows=['my_script']" but I built it with "console=['my_script']", so those fixes didn't help, and I don't need an actual interactive mode (i.e. the REPL), but for some reason the -i switch fixes the console IO issues.

This is the code I'm using to launch it:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();

psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

psi.FileName = "py2exe_program.exe";

Process p = Process.Start(psi);

// program hangs here because ready message is never printed
p.StandardOutput.ReadLine(); // Consume ready message
```

The executable works as expected when launched externally, and the above code works when I launch the Python script via "python.exe -i my_script.py" but it runs into the same problem without the -i switch.

How do I get it to behave as expected?

Comment: Did you try to print the sys.argv content on the console? It should show you what is received by the python app.

Comment: sys.argv only prints arguments received by the script, the -i switch is passed to the interpreter though, the script never sees it.